# Which Substrate version should I use?

Tags: substrate-node-template

I am just starting a new project on substrate.
Which substrate version i should prefer v3.0.0 stable version or the latest version v4.0.0-dev.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend using the latest version of Substrate for any of your projects, otherwise, using an older version will just lead you to need to upgrade at a later point in time.

For parachain teams, everyone is synchronized with the `polkadot-*` branches which correspond to the Substrate versions used to release the [Polkadot releases](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases).

So each time Polkadot has a new release, all the Substrate ecosystem builders update their version of Substrate to the latest release. This is the best cadence to follow.

Comment: This is indeed best practice in production for any chain, solo or parachain, as Polkadot releases are much more intentional in the things included. The alternative now is to be floating on and unspecific version on `master` or perhaps a `monthly` release of Substrate, but updating may introduce braking changes without careful monitoring and add incorporation as desired.

Comment: Another consideration is the removal of the explicit version of packages in your `Cargo.toml` files that depend on some git repository to draw from, as is done in Polkadot for example:
```toml
frame-benchmarking-cli = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", optional = true, branch = "polkadot-v0.9.17" }
```
This way the version is implicit based on the head of the branch/rev/tag set.

Comment: @shawn-tabrizi @dan-shields  What is the difference between the `polkadot-*` branches within the `substrate` repo vs the `polkadot` repo?

And so that I understand, if starting a new Substrate project, developers should not use the `substrate-node-template`, but instead should use the latest polkadot release. Is that correct?